# Why isn't my helper collection query not reflecting in the html template?

Tags: javascript, events, meteor, helper, meteor-publications

Following the tutorial on how to "[Write an API](https://github.com/themeteorchef/writing-an-api/blob/master/writing-an-api.md)", I seem to have gotten stuck and can't move beyond how to get the generated API Key to display in the template.

I have a query `APIKeys.find().fetch()` in the helper that should reflect correctly in the html template, but it doesn't. I have spent hours looking through my code and have failed to notice any errors in my code.

I am not that new to Meteor which makes it all the more annoying!

Kindly help!

Find below the template code:
***/client/main.html***

```
<template name="apiKey">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <h4 class="page-header">Your API Key</h4>
  <p>To gain access to the Pizza API, use the following API Key. 
     Make sure to keep it super safe! <strong>If you'd like to
     generate a new key, click the "refresh" icon on the field
     below</strong>.</p>

  <label class="sr-only" for="apiKey">Your API Key</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="apiKey" placeholder="API Key" value="{{apiKey}}">
    <div class="input-group-addon regenerate-api-key"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the template above, NOTHING is rendered in the template under `value="{{apiKey}}"`. I dont understand why this is.

Find below my helpers code: ***/client/main.js***

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Template.apiKey.helpers({
apiKey: function() {
        var apiKey = APIKeys.findOne();

        if ( apiKey ) {
            return apiKey.key;
            console.log("Sucessful");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed! Can't find: APIKeys.findOne()");    
        }
     }

});
```

The helper code above renders this in the console: `Failed! Can't find: APIKeys.findOne()`.
Further, when I query `APIKeys.find().fetch()` in the console, I get this:

```
[]
```

Find below my onCreated code: ***/client/main.js***

```
Template.apiKey.onCreated(function(){
  console.log("Your in onCreated!");
  this.subscribe( "APIKey" );
});
```

The onCreated code above renders this in the console: `Your in onCreated!`.

Find below my events code that is triggered to generate a new API Key: ***/client/main.js***

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Template.apiKey.events({
'click .regenerate-api-key': function( ){
        var userId = Meteor.userId();
        confirmRegeneration = confirm( "Are you sure? This will 
        invalidate your current key!" );

       if ( confirmRegeneration ) {
          Meteor.call( "regenerateApiKey", userId, function( error, response ) {
       if ( error ) {
          alert( error.reason, "danger" );
       }
       else {
           alert( "All done! You have a new API key: " +response );
           console.log("Response is: " +response);
      }
     });
    }
  }
});
```

The events code above renders a popup box with: `All done! You have a new API key: 0`. Also the console renders: `Response is: 0`.

Find below the `regenerateApiKey` method code ***/server/main.js***

```
Meteor.methods({
  regenerateApiKey: function( userId ){
    check( userId, Meteor.userId() );

    var newKey = Random.hexString( 32 );
    console.log(">>>: " +newKey);

    try {
      var keyId = APIKeys.update( { "owner": userId }, {
        $set: {
          "key": newKey
        }
      });
      console.log(">>> newKey : " +keyId);
      return keyId;

    } catch(exception) {
        console.log("FAILED UPDATE")
      return exception;
    }
  }
});
```

The method code above renders the below in the terminal:

```
>>>: af3233a999308e39f9471b790e121cf5
>>> newKey : 0
```

I have narrowed the issue in the code down to this. The `keyId` variable being equal to "0" suggests that the APIKeys collection isn't getting updated. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I have included further information in hope that it will help.

Find below the code where i subscribe ***/client/main.js***

```
Router.route('/apiKey', {
 template: 'apiKey',

 waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('APIKey');          
    }

});
```

Find below the code where I publish ***/server/main.js***

```
Meteor.publish( 'APIKey', function(){
  var user = this.userId;
  var data = APIKeys.find( { "owner": user }, {fields: { "key": 1 } } );

  if ( data ) {
        console.log("User: " +user+ " data is: " +data);
        console.log("Was able to find data in Publish APIKey!");
        console.log(APIKeys.find().fetch());
    return data;
  }
  return this.ready();
});
```

The publish code above renders the below in the terminal:

```
User: xELzNtMQp7u9FpZib data is: [object Object]
Was able to find data in Publish APIKey!
[]
```

Find below the code where I declare the collection ***imports/api/tasks.js***

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

global.APIKeys = new Meteor.Collection("apiKeys");


/*
* Allow
*/

APIKeys.allow({
  insert: function(){
    // Disallow inserts on the client by default.
    return false;
  },
  update: function(){
    // Disallow updates on the client by default.
    return false;
  },
  remove: function(){
    // Disallow removes on the client by default.
    return false;
  }
});

/*
* Deny
*/

APIKeys.deny({
  insert: function(){
    // Deny inserts on the client by default.
    return true;
  },
  update: function(){
    // Deny updates on the client by default.
    return true;
  },
  remove: function(){
    // Deny removes on the client by default.
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks like you don't have any keys in the database, when you try to update it

Try swapping out `APIKeys.update` for `APIKeys.upsert`, which will create a key if one doesn't exist.

```
try {
  var keyId = APIKeys.upsert( { "owner": userId }, {
    $set: {
      "key": newKey
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for figuring this out! It had been stressing me out for days!